# How to use MotionEvents on ImageView to toggle between images?

Tags: android, image, touch

I try to create an app like the followings:

1. Open the app, show user an image.
2. When user touches the screen, image changes to another one as long as the screen is still pressed.
3. When user stops pressing the screen, the app will go back to the original image.

That's it. I'm new to Android app development and I'm stuck in handling touch events. Thanks for your help. Below is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.salmoon);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lobster);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:src="@drawable/lobster"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

New code (Jul 27 '16):

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/img"
       android:src="@drawable/pic"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:layout_gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

pic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/lobster" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/salmoon"></item>
</selector>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319561/android-selector-for-clickable-layout-with-imageview

Comment: @quicklearner Thanks! Although I didn't follow your example line-by-line, for instance, I made the ImageView clickable instead of the whole layout, it really helps! Love Stack Overflow, love you all!